# Simplification of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{4k^2-1}$

Tags: summation, fractions

So I want to simplify this expression:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{4k^2-1}$$
and Wolfram Alpha tells me it can be simplified to two forms:
$$\frac{n}{2n+1}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2(2n+1)}$$
The problem being that I don't know how to do so and I cannot seem to, after sincerely trying, find any helpful information in my text book nor in Google. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac 1{4k^2 - 1} = \frac 1{(2k + 1)(2k - 1)} = \frac 12\left(\frac{1}{2k - 1} - \frac{1}{2k + 1}\right)$$
So now your sum can collapse to contain only some initial and terminal terms.

Comment: Because of your answer I was able to apply "telescoping" (I believe that's how it's called anyway) and got the second simplification, however, I don't see how you were able to find the transformation of the fraction into the last form. How do I go about finding it? Thanks!

Comment: @sempiedram, you should look up 'partial fraction decomposition'. When you have a fraction with a second degree polynomial (or higher) in the denominator, you can algebraically break it into a sum of fractions with denominators of lower polynomial order

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in what you say.

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{4k^2-1}=\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}.$$
Then, find $A,B$ such that $$\frac{1}{4k^2-1}=\frac{A}{2k-1}+\frac{B}{2k+1},$$
and your sum will follow...

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by: it can be simplified to two form $\frac{n}{2n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2(2n+1)}$ ? You mean $\frac{1}{4k^2-1}$ ? it's of course impossible.

Comment: That the summation is equivalent to those two expressions for an integer n.

Comment: It wasn't clear as you said in your original post. But I anyways answer to your question, since you can now compute the sum.